# How can I access a selected column from my first select-statement in my third-level subslect?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table "Bed" and a table "Component". Between those two I have a m:n relation and the table "BedComponent", where I store the Bed-ID and the Component-ID.
Every Component has a price. And now I want to write a select-statement that gives me the sum of prices for a certain bed.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT Bed.idBed, Bed.name, SUM(src.price) AS summe, Bed.idCustomer
FROM Bed,
(SELECT price
      FROM dbo.Component AS C
      WHERE (C.idComponent IN
            (SELECT idComponent
                FROM dbo.BedComponent AS BC
                WHERE 1 = BC.idBed))) AS src

GROUP BY dbo.Bed.idBed, dbo.Bed.name, dbo.Bed.idCustomer;
```

This statement works. But of course I don't want to write the bed-ID hard coded into my select as it will always calculate the price for bed 1. Instead of the "1" i want to have the current bed-id.

I work with MS SQL Server

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you need to learn `JOIN`.  Sample data and desired results would also help others disentangle the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select b.idBed, b.name, SUM(src.price) AS summe, b.idCustomer
from bed b join
     bedcomponent bc
     on b.idBed = bc.idBed join
     component c
     on c.idComponent = bc.idComponent
group by b.idBed, b.name, b.idCustomer;
```

The `idCustomer` looks strange to me in the `select` and `group by`, but I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Also note the use of table aliases, which make the query easier to write and to read.